# I'm receiving the following error in jmeter 'Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 38:'

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm passing the url from the csv config to http request, I'm facing the following error message - 'Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 38:'

In the view results tree - Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 38: http://my.referrer.com/sweet/referral/ /

Comment: Add more details. Screen shot of CSV File, CSV Data Config, HTTP Sampler, View Results Tree.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you're using the wrong location for the URL variable, you should place the variable under "Path" section of the HTTP Request sampler

[image]

"Server Name or IP" section is only for DNS [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) or IP address, you cannot have anything else there.

Check out [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/) article for example of parameterization of URL path.